# Mongodb Aggregate - Count fields that equals value in array, but keep both arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to calculate the percentage of finalized/total items. The problem I have is calculating how many fields in the array equal to 'finished'. With my current solution I get finished items correctly, but total items are the same number as finished.

This is what I'm doing:

```
Items.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      status: {
        $ne: ['cancelled','pending']
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$person',
      items: {
        $push: {
          total: '$status',
          finished: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: ['$status', 'finished']
              },
              '$status',
              null
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$items'
  },
  {
    $match: {
      'items.finished': {
        $ne: null
      },
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      success: {
        $push : '$items.finished'
      },
      total: {
        $push: '$items.total'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      successCount: {
        $size: '$success'
      },
      totalCount: {
        $size: '$total'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      successScore: {
        $divide: [ "$successCount", "$totalCount"]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

I also tried simpler solution, but can't figure how to keep total count field in the loop after doing `$unwind`

```
Items.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      totalCount: {$sum: 1},
      finished: { $cond : [ {$eg: ['status', 'finished']}, $status, null] }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: '$finished'},
  ...
```

Then I can't access totalCount later

Comment: Could you clarify a bit by perhaps throwing in a bunch of documents for testing and then show us the expected aggregation output from that sample?

Comment: Try removing the `$match` clause on `items.finished` before grouping